# Is there any way to refresh dashboards on load as of Spring 16 release?

Tags: javascript, automation, user-interface

Is there any way to refresh dynamic dashboards on page load anymore?
We used to be able to put in JS that "clicked" the refresh button for our users but that appears to be defunct as of Spring '16.